# How do I ignore words containing substrings using componentsSeparatedByString:?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I would like to parse the following string using `-componentsSeparatedByString:`:

```
     CHAPTER 5. RULE OF DECISION
 CHAPTER 6. GOVERNMENTAL EXEMPTION FROM BOND AND SECURITY REQUIREMENTS
 CHAPTER 7. LIABILITY OF COURT OFFICERS
     SUBCHAPTER A. LIABILITY OF OFFICER
     SUBCHAPTER B. LIABILITY OF ATTORNEY
     SUBCHAPTER C. SUIT ON OFFICIAL BONDS
 CHAPTER 8. STATE EXEMPTION FROM CERTAIN FEES: FEES PAID BY OPPOSING PARTY
 CHAPTER 9. FRIVOLOUS PLEADINGS AND CLAIMS
     SUBCHAPTER A. GENERAL PROVISIONS
     SUBCHAPTER B. SIGNING OF PLEADINGS
 CHAPTER 10. SANCTIONS FOR FRIVOLOUS PLEADINGS AND MOTIONS
```

but when I use `CHAPTER` as the string to separate by, the SUBCHAPTER elements also get broken up because they contain CHAPTER within them.

How can I avoid stopping on the SUBCHAPTER elements when parsing the CHAPTER ones using -componentsSeparatedByString:?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**regular expressions** regexKit is perfect for this](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/). That will help you to form the exact pattern you are looking for...

```
NSString *regex      = @"^CHAPTER [0-9]";
NSPredicate *valtest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex]; 
ret                  = [valtest evaluateWithObject:yourText];
NSLog("Matches: %@", ret);
```